# Why does dynamically changing the WindowStyle have no effect on my application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Some Background: I am working on an application in C#, WPF, and .NET 4.6.1.

I had a small issue. I defined a Custom WindowChrome instead of the default one Windows provides. I set WindowStyle="None" in my header and then defined the following in my MainApplication XAML page:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome 
        ResizeBorderThickness="6"
        CaptionHeight="20"
        GlassFrameThickness="0"
        CornerRadius="0"
        />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Now I ran into a particular issue. I lost some of the animation functionality that you get as part of windows when you minimize a window and I wanted that instead of the application simply closing. Some answers here on StackOverFlow suggested I try a number of things including setting the WindowStyle to SingleBorderWindow when the minimize event is triggered and then un-setting it after to regain that functionality. And this worked!!!

Now I did something different and it also works and it has no effect on my application's look and I have no idea why it works. Instead of doing the solution above, I set my WindowStyle to SingleBorderWindow in the XAML and it works!!! My window looks exactly the same as if WindowStyle were set to None or alternatively, after InitializeComponents() is called in the constructor, I simply put this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow. Again this has no effect on the look of my application.

Why?

Comment: If you overrided default chrome, than you need to define change window style behaviour by yourself.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I don't understand, I'm kinda new to this. I did change window style by myself. The problem is, when I do, it makes no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only difference between WindowStyle 'None' and 'SingleBorderWindow' is the WindowChrome that you have overridden, so you won't see any difference on using any WindowStyle